# How can I assign the values of state to another object?

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs, react-native, mobile-application

I have tried everything below.  
Is there a reason why it is not working?  
Are there any suggestions?  
Thank you for your kind replies.

```
addInfo = () => {
  const hash = this.state.hash;
  //test if all required fields are provided
  if (this.state.firstName && this.state.lastName) {
    allMap[hash] = Object.assign(this.state);
    /*
    tried these too
    allMap[hash] = Object.assign({}, this.state);
    allMap[hash] = {...this.state};
    allMap[hash] = this.state
    */
    this.reset();
  } else {
    alert("please fill the required fields")
  }
};
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Please post your full code.

Comment: It's is not assigning,allMap[key] still results in undefined

Comment: What's the value of `key` ?

Comment: It is a unique id, automatically generated at componentDidMount or this.reset()

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're not assigning it to anything, your first argument should be an empty `{}`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

```
 allMap[hash] = Object.assign({}, this.state);
```

Alternatively you could do:

```
 allMap[hash] = {...this.state}
```

Comment: I've tried those too, even direct assignment (allMap[hash] = this.state). Thanks

Comment: For the record, you should never assign state directly to any variable, that will be stored as a reference and you will run into loads of issues. If you did the spread operator and it didn't work then the problem with your code is elsewhere, both methods above are valid ways of cloning an object and assigning the value to a variable

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably figure out another way to save those informations, but could you perhaps provide any reason why it is considered bad?

Comment: Sure of course, so if you do something like `let myVar = this.state` what most people think is happening is that `myVar` becomes an identical version of `this.state` but what actually happens is that `myVar` becomes an alias of `this.state`. So in this situation if you altered a property on `myVar` for example `myVar["id"] = 3` that property is going to change on `this.state` too. This is bad practice with normal objects but especially bad in react because state should never be altered directly.

Comment: Oh yeah, I get it. I was think more of the line of assign(Object.assign). Yeah, absolutely I agree, using direct assignment for objects creates a new reference to that object. I only tried that to see if it would work after everything else failed.